# Why does my MakeFile work with one toolchain make.exe but not MinGW's make.exe

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

My Project:

```
SafeRTOS_VNP_RDB2_MakeFile\
-> board\
-> Common\
-> generate\
-> include\
-> Project_Settings\
-> RTD\
-> SafeRTOS\
-> src\
-> SW32_RTD_4_4_3_0_2_D2203\
-> Makefile
-> (Debug_RAM - where .o's are saved)
```

I've been using a MakeFile to build my project (full file is below) in Eclipse and its been working perfectly. I recently moved to a new PC so installed make again - using MinGW's sys tools - and found that it no longer built. I've tried building in Eclipse and on the command line, both of which worked before but now produce the following error:

> 16:45:15 **** Build of configuration Default for project
> SafeRTOS_VNP_RDB2_MakeFile **** make all  mkdir Debug_RAM 2> NUL
> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2728] (c) Microsoft Corporation.
> All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Data\SafeRTOS_VNP_RDB2_MakeFile>Microsoft Windows [Version
> 10.0.19044.2728] (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> C:\Data\SafeRTOS_VNP_RDB2_MakeFile>"C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Arm
> Embedded Toolchain\10 2021.10/bin/"arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall
> -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wextra -c -fno-short-enums -funsigned-bitfields -fno-common -Wunused -Wstrict-prototypes -Wsign-compare -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wundef -Wdouble-promotion  -O0 -funsigned-char -fstack-usage -fdump-ipa-all -fomit-frame-pointer -g3 -ggdb3 -pedantic -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mthumb -mlittle-endian -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv5-sp-d16 -specs=nano.specs -specs=nosys.specs --sysroot="C:\nxp\S32DS.3.5\eclipse../S32DS/build_tools/gcc_v9.2/gcc-9.2-arm32-eabi/arm-none-eabi/newlib"
> -I"SafeRTOS/api/252_ARMv7M_MPU" -I"SafeRTOS/api/PrivWrapperStd" -I"SafeRTOS/config" -I"SafeRTOS/kernel/include_api" -I"SafeRTOS/kernel/include_prv" -I"SafeRTOS/portable/252_ARMv7M_MPU" -I"SafeRTOS/portable/252_ARMv7M_MPU/003_GCC"  -I"Common/include" -I"include" -I"RTD/include" -I"generate/include" -I"board" -I"Common/include" -I"include" -I"C:\nxp\S32DS.3.5\eclipse../S32DS/software/PlatformSDK_S32XX_2022_03/SW32_RTD_4_4_3_0_2_D2203/Base_TS_T40D11M30I2R0/header"
> -I"C:\nxp\S32DS.3.5\eclipse../S32DS/software/PlatformSDK_S32XX_2022_03/SW32_RTD_4_4_3_0_2_D2203/Base_TS_T40D11M30I2R0/include" -I"C:\nxp\S32DS.3.5\eclipse../S32DS/software/PlatformSDK_S32XX_2022_03/SW32_RTD_4_4_3_0_2_D2203/Platform_TS_T40D11M30I2R0/startup/include"
> -DUSE_SW_VECTOR_MODE -DD_CACHE_ENABLE -DI_CACHE_ENABLE -DENABLE_FPU -DMPU_ENABLE -DGCC -DCPU_S32G274A -DS32G2XX -DCPU_CORTEX_M7  -MMD -MP -MF"Debug_RAM/exceptions.d" -c -o"Debug_RAM/exceptions.o" "./Project_Settings/Startup_Code/exceptions.c" The system cannot find
> the path specified. make: *** [Debug_RAM/exceptions.o] Error 1 "make
> all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.
>
> 16:46:11 Build Failed. 1 errors, 0 warnings. (took 56s.417ms)

[Eclipse Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5b2Nf.png)

I've certified that the gcc tool has the correct file path for both new and old PC's, so I'm not sure if the error message is spurious or if it's referring to a different file path in the command. In fact, it can't even run the "$ make version" section of the script as it seems to produce very strange results.

For example, running "$ make version" on my old PC produces this output:

> C:\Data\SafeRTOS_VNP_RDB2_MakeFile>make version C:\Program Files
> (x86)\GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain\10 2021.10 arm-none-eabi-
> C:/WINDOWS/system32/cmd.exe C:\Program Files\Amazon
> Corretto\jdk1.8.0_362\bin;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\Strawberry\c\BROKEN;C:\Program
> Files\HighTec\toolchains\tricore\v4.9.4.1\bin;C:\Program
> Files\HighTec\licensemanager;C:\Program
> Files\HighTec\toolchains\tricore\v4.9.2.0\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Amazon Corretto\jre8;C:\Program Files
> (x86)\STMicroelectronics\STM32 ST-LINK Utility\ST-LINK
> Utility;C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI
> Foundation\VISA\WinNT\Bin;C:\Program Files\IVI
> Foundation\VISA\Win64\Bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\IVI
> Foundation\VISA\WinNT\Bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program
> Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin;C:\Program
> Files\OpenJDK\jdk-8.0.292.10-hotspot\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\bin;C:\Program
> Files\CMake\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY;C:\Program
> Files\dotnet;C:\Users\slimjo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts;C:\Users\slimjo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310;C:\Users\slimjo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Launcher;C:\Users\slimjo\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
> ==================================== Running compiler to check version: version Missing input file.
>
> Usage: version.bat option or version.bat object
>
> ### Known options:
>
> ### --version : Print version number
>
> --help    : Print this help screen

[cmd.exe output of $ make version #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pb8AG.png)

but on my new PC it gives this:

> C:\Data\SafeRTOS_VNP_RDB2_MakeFile>make version
> Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.2728]
> (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

[cmd.exe output of $ make version #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVaAn.png)

I tried replacing the `version:` target functionality so it would simply print a string e.g.

```
version: 
    @echo "This is a toolchain"
    @echo "This is a toolchain"
    @echo "This is a toolchain"
```

but it *still* produced the output on the previous image.

After some digging, i've discovered that the make.exe i was using on my old PC was from HighTec's IDE:

```
$ where make
C:\Program Files\HighTec\toolchains\tricore\v4.9.4.1\bin\make.exe
```

So i'm wondering:

1. Is there a significant difference between make.exe 's for different toolchains?
2. Is there an error in my MakeFile that HighTec's .exe doesn't spot/doesn't care about? And if so what?

Thanks for any help you can provide.

---

```
ifdef COMSPEC
    SHELL := ${COMSPEC}
else ifdef ComSpec
    SHELL := ${ComSpec}
else
    SHELL := cmd.exe
endif

# NOTE: Set TOOLCHAIN_ROOT to reflect the path to the desired cross compiler. 
# This may be set here, or by defining an environment variable TOOLCHAIN_ROOT.
ifndef TOOLCHAIN_ROOT
    TOOLCHAIN_ROOT := C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Arm Embedded Toolchain\10 2021.10
endif

ifndef NXP_S32DS_INSTALL_PATH
    NXP_S32DS_INSTALL_PATH := C:\nxp\S32DS.3.5\eclipse\../
endif

CROSS_COMPILE   := arm-none-eabi-

OBJDIR          := Debug_RAM
APPNAME         := SafeRTOS_VNP_RDB2_MakeFile

CC              := "${TOOLCHAIN_ROOT}/bin/"${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc
AS              := "${TOOLCHAIN_ROOT}/bin/"${CROSS_COMPILE}as
LD              := "${TOOLCHAIN_ROOT}/bin/"${CROSS_COMPILE}gcc

SIZE            := "${TOOLCHAIN_ROOT}/bin/"${CROSS_COMPILE}size
OBJCOPY         := "${TOOLCHAIN_ROOT}/bin/"${CROSS_COMPILE}objcopy

RM              := rm -rf

# Processor options.
ARCH_FLAGS = -mcpu=cortex-m7 -mthumb -mlittle-endian -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv5-sp-d16

C_FLAGS := -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wextra -c -fno-short-enums -funsigned-bitfields -fno-common -Wunused -Wstrict-prototypes -Wsign-compare -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -Wundef -Wdouble-promotion 
C_FLAGS += -O0 -funsigned-char -fstack-usage -fdump-ipa-all -fomit-frame-pointer -g3 -ggdb3 -pedantic ${ARCH_FLAGS}
C_FLAGS += -specs=nano.specs -specs=nosys.specs --sysroot="${NXP_S32DS_INSTALL_PATH}S32DS/build_tools/gcc_v9.2/gcc-9.2-arm32-eabi/arm-none-eabi/newlib"

ASM_FLAGS := -c -x assembler-with-cpp -g3
ASM_FLAGS += $(ARCH_FLAGS)
ASM_FLAGS += -specs=nano.specs -specs=nosys.specs --sysroot="${NXP_S32DS_INSTALL_PATH}S32DS/build_tools/gcc_v9.2/gcc-9.2-arm32-eabi/arm-none-eabi/newlib"


LD_FLAGS := -nostartfiles --entry=Reset_Handler -ggdb3 
# LD_FLAGS += -T "./Project_Settings/Linker_Files/linker_ram.ld"
LD_FLAGS += -Wl,-Map,"${APPNAME}.map"
LD_FLAGS += $(ARCH_FLAGS)
LD_FLAGS += -specs=nano.specs -specs=nosys.specs --sysroot="${NXP_S32DS_INSTALL_PATH}S32DS/build_tools/gcc_v9.2/gcc-9.2-arm32-eabi/arm-none-eabi/newlib"


default: all

version: 
    @echo ${TOOLCHAIN_ROOT}
    @echo ${CROSS_COMPILE}
    @echo ${SHELL}
    @echo ${PATH}
    @echo ====================================
    @echo Running compiler to check version:
    $(COMPILER) --version

# this throws away any error message for if the directory already exists
$(OBJDIR):
    -mkdir $(OBJDIR) 2> NUL


SAFERTOS_SUBDIRS = \
    ./SafeRTOS/kernel \
    ./SafeRTOS/api/252_ARMv7M_MPU \
    ./SafeRTOS/api/PrivWrapperStd \
    ./SafeRTOS/portable/252_ARMv7M_MPU \
    ./SafeRTOS/portable/252_ARMv7M_MPU/003_GCC \


SAFERTOS_INCLUDE_PATH := \
    -I"SafeRTOS/api/252_ARMv7M_MPU" \
    -I"SafeRTOS/api/PrivWrapperStd" \
    -I"SafeRTOS/config" \
    -I"SafeRTOS/kernel/include_api" \
    -I"SafeRTOS/kernel/include_prv" \
    -I"SafeRTOS/portable/252_ARMv7M_MPU" \
    -I"SafeRTOS/portable/252_ARMv7M_MPU/003_GCC" \

SAFERTOS_CSRCS = $(foreach dir, $(SAFERTOS_SUBDIRS), $(wildcard $(dir)/*.c))
SAFERTOS_SSRCS = $(foreach dir, $(SAFERTOS_SUBDIRS), $(wildcard $(dir)/*.s))


DEMO_SUBDIRS = \
    ./Project_Settings/Startup_Code \
    ./RTD/src \
    ./board \
    ./generate/src \
    ./src \
    ./Common \


DEMO_INCLUDE_PATH = \
    -I"Common/include" \
    -I"include" \
    -I"RTD/include" \
    -I"generate/include" \
    -I"board" \
    -I"Common/include" \
    -I"include" \
    -I"SW32_RTD_4_4_3_0_2_D2203/Base_TS_T40D11M30I2R0/header" \
    -I"SW32_RTD_4_4_3_0_2_D2203/Base_TS_T40D11M30I2R0/include" \
    -I"SW32_RTD_4_4_3_0_2_D2203/Platform_TS_T40D11M30I2R0/startup/include" \

DEMO_SRCS = $(foreach dir, $(DEMO_SUBDIRS), $(wildcard $(dir)/*.c)) 

EXCLUDES := \
    ./Common/comtest.c \
    ./src/serial.c \

CSRC := $(filter-out $(EXCLUDES),$(DEMO_SRCS))

DEMO_DEFINES += -DUSE_SW_VECTOR_MODE -DD_CACHE_ENABLE -DI_CACHE_ENABLE -DENABLE_FPU -DMPU_ENABLE -DGCC -DCPU_S32G274A -DS32G2XX -DCPU_CORTEX_M7


THIRD_PARTY_SUBDIRS = 
THIRD_PARTY_INCLUDE_PATH = 
THIRD_PARTY_DEFINES = 
THIRD_PARTY_SRCS = $(foreach dir, $(THIRD_PARTY_SUBDIRS), $(wildcard $(dir)/*.c))

S_SRCS = \
    /Project_Settings/Startup_Code/startup_cm7.s \
    /Project_Settings/Startup_Code/Vector_Table.s \

LINKER_SCRIPT   := ./Project_Settings/Linker_Files/linker_ram.ld


C_SRCS = $(CSRC) $(SAFERTOS_CSRCS) $(THIRD_PARTY_SRCS)
S_SRCS += $(SAFERTOS_SSRCS)

VPATH = $(DEMO_SUBDIRS) $(SAFERTOS_SUBDIRS) $(THIRD_PARTY_SUBDIRS)


OBJ_NAMES = $(notdir $(C_SRCS))
OBJS = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(OBJ_NAMES:%.c=%.o))

SOBJ_NAMES = $(notdir $(S_SRCS:%.S=%.s))
OBJS += $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(SOBJ_NAMES:%.s=%.o))

C_DEPS = $(OBJS:%.o=%.d)

DEFINES = $(DEMO_DEFINES) $(THIRD_PARTY_DEFINES)
INCLUDES = $(SAFERTOS_INCLUDE_PATH) $(DEMO_INCLUDE_PATH) $(THIRD_PARTY_INCLUDE_PATH)

ifneq ($(MAKECMDGOALS),clean)
    -include $(C_DEPS)
endif

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.s
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking:  ${CC}'
    $(CC) $(ASM_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(DEFINES) -o"$@" -c "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '
    
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
    @echo 'Building file: $<'
    @echo 'Invoking:  ${CC}'
    $(CC) $(C_FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) $(DEFINES) -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)" -c -o"$@" "$<"
    @echo 'Finished building: $<'
    @echo ' '

EXECUTABLES += \
    ${APPNAME}.elf \


# All Target
all: $(EXECUTABLES) secondary-outputs

# Tool invocations
${APPNAME}.elf: $(OBJDIR) $(OBJS) ${LINKER_SCRIPT} Makefile
    @echo 'Building target: $@'
    $(LD) -Bstatic $(LD_FLAGS) \
        -T ${LINKER_SCRIPT} \
        -Wl,-Map="${APPNAME}.map" \
        $(OBJS) \
        -o ${APPNAME}.elf
    @echo 'Finished building target: $@'
    @echo ' '
    $(MAKE) --no-print-directory post-build
    ${OBJCOPY} -O binary ${APPNAME}.elf ${APPNAME}.bin


# Other Targets
clean:
    $(RM) $(C_DEPS) $(EXECUTABLES) "${APPNAME}.map" "${APPNAME}.bin"
    $(RM) $(OBJDIR)


post-build:
    $(SIZE) "${APPNAME}.elf"
    @echo ' '


secondary-outputs:


.PHONY: all clean dependents version
.SECONDARY: post-build
```

Comment: [Don't post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)! Copy-paste any and all text *as text*  into your questions.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude apologies, the gcc commands can often be _really_ long so thought images might be more concise

Comment: Please use code block formatting, not quoting, for examples.  Else the lines are all run together and we can't tell what's what.  Yes, definitely it means we have to scroll to see the end of the line but that's better than not being able to figure out where one line ends and another begins.

Comment: To answer your question more directly, there are lots of different implementations of `make`.  The one in MinGW is GNU Make, but there are others and they are only superficially compatible.  The makefile you show definitely needs GNU Make.  You can try running `make.exe --version` for the various different `make` programs you are using and see what the results are.